# Python list swap only working on some iterations

Tags: python, sorting, swap

I'm having trouble with a swapping problem in Python - I want to sort a list of integers by iterating through it and swapping any value that is out of place with the value that should be in that place.
I know the input will be an unsorted list of consecutive integers starting from 1, e.g. [4, 3, 1, 2]

```
sorted = [4, 3, 1, 2]
swapCount = 0
for i in range(len(sorted)):
  if sorted[i] != i + 1:
    print(f"Before swap {i + 1}: {sorted}")
    sorted[i], sorted[sorted.index(i + 1)] = sorted[sorted.index(i + 1)], sorted[i]
    swapCount += 1
    print(f"After swap {i + 1}: {sorted}")
    
print(swapCount)
```

```
# Before swap 1: [4, 3, 1, 2]
# After swap 1: [4, 3, 1, 2]
# Before swap 2: [4, 3, 1, 2]
# After swap 2: [4, 3, 1, 2]
# Before swap 3: [4, 3, 1, 2]
# After swap 3: [4, 1, 3, 2]
# Before swap 4: [4, 1, 3, 2]
# After swap 4: [2, 1, 3, 4]
# 4
```

So in my loop, the swap doesn't work (or works in some special cases), while the same syntax works outside a loop:

```
sorted = [4, 3, 1, 2, 5]
print(sorted)
sorted[0], sorted[2] = sorted[2], sorted[0]
print(sorted)
```

```
# [4, 3, 1, 2, 5]
# [1, 3, 4, 2, 5]
```

Can anyone help me understand what's going wrong in the loop?

Comment: `i+1` is an index, so why are you comparing against it?

Comment: Because `i + 1` is the value that should be at index `i` because the input will always be a list starting from 1.

Comment: Why do you need to sort it in the first place?

Comment: Just to be sure, are you trying to implement [bubble sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/bubble_sort)?

Comment: The assignment to `sorted[i]` happens before the call to `sorted.index` determines the target of the next assignment. That is, you are probably getting two different return values from the two calls to `sorted.index`.

Comment: @chepner, it's not perfectly clear to me, but I see this is the problem - if I use a separate variable to store the index first, the code works. I'll have to look into the python swap function a bit more. Thank you for helping

Comment: @DeepSpace, yes, not bubble sort as I am not looking at adjacent values specifically.

Comment: Basically, an assignment like `a, b = c, d` is equivalent to `t = c, d; a = t[0]; b = t[1]`. Any side effects caused by the evaluation of `a` take place before `b` is evaluated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An assignment like `a, b = c, d` first uses the right-hand side to define a tuple. Then the first element is assigned to `a`, and then the second element is assigned to `b`. The first assignment may include a side effect that could affect the second; they do not happened simultaneously or independently.

Your code

```
sorted[i], sorted[sorted.index(i + 1)] = sorted[sorted.index(i + 1)], sorted[i]
```

is equivalent to

```
t = sorted[sorted.index(i + 1)], sorted[i]
sorted[i] = t[0]
sorted[sorted.index(i+1)] = t[1]
```

Note, in particular, that between the two calls to `sorted.index` is an assignment that changes `sorted`, and thus could cause the second `sorted.index` to return a different value than the first.

You want to call `sorted.index(i+1)` first and save its value, then use the saved value in the swap.

```
j = sorted.index(i+1)
sorted[i], sorted[j] = sorted[j], sorted[i]
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation - that's great!